# How can I use this javascript to work on 8 different modals with different IDs without having to repeat the same code to each button?

Tags: javascript

Source code for the modal content for one button

```
<script>
  var modal = getElementById("myModal");
  var btn = getElementById("myBtn");
  var span = getElementByClassName("close")[0];

  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  span.onclik = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am a new member to the community ! Sorry for misarrangement!  Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Use a `class` for buttons and modals instead of `id`s

Comment: Put it in a function, call that function with different ids.

Comment: Btw, did you mean `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: @adiga thanks dear. But I thought that each button and modal  should have a different class from another because they will be used to display different content on the same page?

Comment: @Bergi i will definitely try that thanks 

Answer (score -1):

You might also look into using JQuery.
if you include the JQuery Library with your javascript code, then you can target the DOM elements like this:

$('.myBtn').on('click', function(event) { // Do something here. });

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply.  Let me try that and let you know what happened.  Thanks once again

Comment: That wouldn't work with the OP's current code - you're targeting the *class* `myBtn`, which doesn't exist.